# Spring MVC save uploaded MultipartFile to specific folder

Tags: spring, file, tomcat, file-upload

I want to save uploaded images to a specific folder in a Spring 3 MVC application deployed on Tomcat

My problem is that I cannot save the uploaded images files to the host where the appliciation is running.

Here is what I tried:

```
private void saveFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, int id) throws Exception {
    String destination = "/images/" + id + "/"  + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    File file = new File(destination);
    multipartFile.transferTo(file);
}
```

Result: FileNotFoundException - Yes sure, I do want create this file!?!

I tried it using the `context.getRealPath` or `getResources("destination")`, but without any success.

How can I create a new file in a specific folder of my app with the content of my multipart file?

Comment: What errors did you get when you tried context.getRealPath or getResources("destination") see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970643/create-a-file-and-store-in-java-web-application-folder

Comment: Ah okay thanks, getRealPath didn't work, because it returns null if the app got deployed into a war file and was not extracted! Its working outside of the war container! But are there any options to get the path to a file inside of a war?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. It doesn't really make sense to add files into a deployed war. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: No not really, but I read that some webservers do not extract the war file so that I thought to make the above example possible, there must be a way to write in that war directory. Therfore getRealPath is not the proper method cause it'll return null.
Fortunately it is working on my tomcat, but just to briden my horizont I would like to know if there is another solution

Comment: FileNotFoundException means you don't have folder /images/{id}/, you should create folder first.

Answer (score 43):

This  code will surely help you.

```
String filePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); 
multipartFile.transferTo(new File(filePath));
```

Comment: but without using the http servlet request how can we get the path..?

Comment: There are many way: You can use request or session to get the real path. Thanks Ravi. M

Comment: @JijeshKumar easiest way to send a parameter of type HttpServletRequest  in the controller

Answer (score 20):

Let's create the **uploads** directory in webapp and save files in **webapp/uploads**:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingController.class);

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public
        @ResponseBody
        ResponseEntity handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    String uploadsDir = "/uploads/";
                    String realPathtoUploads =  request.getServletContext().getRealPath(uploadsDir);
                    if(! new File(realPathtoUploads).exists())
                    {
                        new File(realPathtoUploads).mkdir();
                    }

                    log.info("realPathtoUploads = {}", realPathtoUploads);


                    String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
                    String filePath = realPathtoUploads + orgName;
                    File dest = new File(filePath);
                    file.transferTo(dest);
```

the code
`String realPathtoUploads =  request.getServletContext().getRealPath(uploadsDir);`

returns me next path if I run the app from Idea IDE
`C:\Users\Iuliia\IdeaProjects\ENumbersBackend\src\main\webapp\uploads\`

and next path if I make .war and run it under Tomcat:
`D:\Programs_Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.27\webapps\enumbservice-0.2.0\uploads\`

My project structure:

[image]

Comment: The last line of the code ' file.transferTo(dest);' gives me IO exception and the error message is "The system cannot find the path specified". Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @AND, are you sure the path is exist in your file system? You need to create directories firstly (manually or programmatically).

Comment: This was very helpful. While its effectively the same answer as Ravi's, this is a more thorough answer.
This answer is still valid in Spring Boot 1.5.10

Answer (score 14):

You can get the inputStream from multipartfile and copy it to any directory you want.

```
public String write(MultipartFile file, String fileType) throws IOException {
    String date = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMddHHmmss-"));
    String fileName = date + file.getOriginalFilename();
    
    // folderPath here is /sismed/temp/exames
    String folderPath = SismedConstants.TEMP_DIR + fileType;
    String filePath = folderPath + File.separator + fileName;
    
    // Copies Spring's multipartfile inputStream to /sismed/temp/exames (absolute path)
    Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), Paths.get(filePath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    return filePath;
}
```

This works for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: good example. just replaced "/" with File.separator

Comment: But not working in Mac

Answer (score 1):

I saw a spring 3 example using xml configuration (note this does not wok for spring 4.2.*): http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring3/mvc/spring3-mvc-upload-file.html
`

```html
<bean id="multipartResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
<property name="uploadTempDir" ref="uploadDirResource" />
</bean>

<bean id="uploadDirResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
<constructor-arg>
<value>C:/test111</value>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String ApplicationPath = 
        ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
```

This is how to get the real path of App in Spring (without using response, session ...)

Comment: you shouldn't use `getRealPath()` to save files.. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12160863/3891638)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on ubuntu:

```
String filePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
File f1 = new File(filePath+"/"+multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
multipartFile.transferTo(f1);
```