# JHipster How to save files in filesystem?

Tags: java, jhipster

JHipster offers the possibility to use the type ImageBlob and AnyBlob in creating entities that have a property that is an image or any type of file respectively. With this option, the files are saved in database, but I would like to know if JHipster offers the ability to save files in the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No JHipster does not offer this feature, it's up you to code it. There are plenty of examples on the web.

Here is one: [Spring MVC save uploaded MultipartFile to specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847994/spring-mvc-save-uploaded-multipartfile-to-specific-folder)

Comment: Thanks Gaël, can you give me an example to integrate this feature in optimal way with JHipster?

Comment: Just added an example from a similar question.

Comment: So understand that when I generated an entity that has a field image then have to modify the code for the front-end image is charge URL and modify the database so that the image column is a string (name image) and not a BLOB. It is correct?