# How to create folder from code in java web application project structure?

Tags: java

Can anyone suggest any ideas how to create a folder in java web application's project structure from code?

Comment: What? please try to explain a bit more what you want to achieve

Comment: duplicate.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024002/how-to-create-a-folder-in-java

Comment: Actually i know how to create a folder in java. But in my java web application, i want to create a folder in the project structure. Also, in that folder i want to create an xml file. This folder should come under the web project structure itself. In a core java application, we can create the folder in the project structure. But in a java web application it is confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about creating a folder within the servletcontainer/webappContext..
here's how to do it :

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp){
      String path = req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
      File f = new File (path +"myNewFolder");
      f.mkdir();

}
```

Comment: Our web project have mainly jsp pages and java files. There are no servlet related classes. In this situation, what can we do?

Comment: In JSP scriplet code, the implicit object `application` refers to the same Servlet context. So the above code can be written as `<% String path = application.getRealPath("/");
      File f = new File (path +"myNewFolder");
      f.mkdir(); %>`

Comment: See also here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970643/create-a-file-and-store-in-java-web-application-folder?rq=1

Comment: Thanks 'Radu Toader' for the above code posted. It helped us!

Answer (score 1):

Found this :

```
File f = new File("C:\\Test");
try{
  if(f.mkdir()) { 
    System.out.println("Directory Created");
  } else {
      System.out.println("Directory is not created");
  }
 } catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

at [How to create a folder in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024002/how-to-create-a-folder-in-java)

Hope it helps

Comment: Here, in the sample provided above, the file 'Test' is saving to C drive. But could you help me how to automatically save a file into a java web project structure (web project in eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    String absolute = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toExternalForm();
    absolute = absolute.substring(0, absolute.length()-1);
    absolute = absolute.substring(0, absolute.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    String xmlPath = absolute + "webapp/xml/";       
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if(os.indexOf("Windows") != -1) {
        xmlPath = xmlPath.replace("/", "\\\\");
        if(xmlPath.indexOf("file:\\\\") != -1) {
        xmlPath = xmlPath.replace("file:\\\\", "");
        }
    } else if(xmlPath.indexOf("file:") != -1) {
        xmlPath = xmlPath.replace("file:", "");
    }

    File f = new File(xmlPath);
    f.mkdir();
```